# UnsupportedOperationException on Collection

Tags: java, exception, collections

While studying the `Collection` API, we find that some methods (`add`, `remove`,...) may throw a `java.lang.UnsupportedOperationException` if the current implementation of the Collection does not support those functionalities.

Is there,actually, in the JDK, a concrete `Collection` that does not support those methods ?

Thanks a lot for your answers.

Comment: May be helpful: http://www.google.com/codesearch?hl=en&q=%22throw+new+UnsupportedOperationException%22+package:%22http://hg.openjdk.java.net/jdk7/l10n/jdk%22&filter=0p&sa=N&cd=7&ct=rm

Answer (score 22, accepted):

The obvious examples are the implementations returned from, say, `Collections.unmodifiableCollection()` and other similar methods. Methods that would change the `Collection` throw this exception.

Comment: Ok. It seems to be logic. Thanks.
And what about the current (modifiable) implementations of the JDK ? I suppose that all thoses classes does not throw this exception ?

Answer (score 30):

Apart from the collections returned by the [`Collections.unmodifiable*`](http://java.sun.com/javase/6/docs/api/java/util/Collections.html) methods, there are a couple more of interesting cases where `UnsupportedOperationException` is actually thrown:

- the collection views of a [`Map`](http://java.sun.com/javase/6/docs/api/java/util/Map.html), accessed via [`entrySet()`](http://java.sun.com/javase/6/docs/api/java/util/Map.html#entrySet%28%29), [`keySet()`](http://java.sun.com/javase/6/docs/api/java/util/Map.html#keySet()) and [`values()`](http://java.sun.com/javase/6/docs/api/java/util/Map.html#values()) can have elements removed but not added,
- the list view returned by [`Arrays.asList`](http://java.sun.com/javase/6/docs/api/java/util/Arrays.html#asList(T...)) can have elements neither added nor removed,
- moreover, the objects obtained from the `Collections.empty*` and `Collections.singleton*` methods are also marked as *"immutable"*, so - although it is not explicitly stated in the API docs - I suppose these throw the exception as well on attempts to modify them.

Comment: I got the exception when I try to remove an element from a list created through Arrays.asList(...)

Answer (score 19):

Normally when you create a list like `List<String> sample=Collections.emptyList();`. The List `sample` will be created as a `Collections.unmodifiableCollection()`.

- So the list sample does not support dynamic list operations. You can only assign another list to this list using assignment operator. Eg>

  ```
  List<String> ls=new ArrayList<String>();
  ls.add("one");
  ls.add("Three");
  ls.add("two");
  ls.add("four"); 
  sample = ls;
  ```
- For dynamic list operations you should have a syntax like 
      `List<String> sample= new ArrayList<String>();`. In this list you can perform `sample.add(), sample.addAll()` etc...

Comment: Downvoted as misleading, because `sample = ls` is pointless : variable assignment operations always succeed, and work the same no matter what the assigned-to variable previously refered to. And, by the way, he intermediate `ls` variable is useless ; one would produce the exact same behaviour doing `sample = new ArrayList<String>(); sample.add("blah");` in the first place.

Comment: @AlainBECKER Good to see comment for the answer written 10 years ago. I agree with your comment because I see ppl might get mislead. However intention for the answer is different.

Answer (score 4):

Yes. For example when you call `Collections.unmodifiableList(list)`, the returned list does not support `add(..)`

These collections, however, are mostly private classes which are not exposed an an API, so you cannot instantiate them.

Comment: Thanks Bozho, for this answer too ;-)