# Implementing Filter/Search functionality in ListAdapter returns UnsupportedOperationException

Tags: java, android, adapter, listadapter

I am trying to implement search functionality in my Adapter class that extends `ListAdapter`. I am not using `RecyclerAdapter` but instead I am using [ListAdapter](https://developer.android.com/reference/androidx/recyclerview/widget/ListAdapter). In main activity to for searching field I am using `EditText` and `addTextChangedListener`. I am having this exception:

[image: exception]

This is my code:

```
public class NoteAdapter extends ListAdapter<Note, NoteAdapter.NoteHolder> implements Filterable {
    private List<Note> mNoteListInit;
    private OnItemClickListener mListener;

    public NoteAdapter() {
        super(DIFF_CALLBACK);
        exampleListFull = new ArrayList<>(getCurrentList());
    } 

    @Override
    public Filter getFilter() {
        return exampleFilter;
    }
    
    public void setInitList(List<Note> noteList) {
        mNoteListInit = new ArrayList<>(noteList);
    }


    private Filter exampleFilter = new Filter() {
        @Override
        protected FilterResults performFiltering(CharSequence constraint) {
            List<Note> filteredList = new ArrayList<>();

            if (constraint == null || constraint.length() == 0) {
                filteredList.addAll(mNoteListInit);
            } else {
                String filterPattern = constraint.toString().toLowerCase().trim();

                for (Note note : mNoteListInit) {
                    if (note.getTitle().toLowerCase().contains(filterPattern)) {
                        filteredList.add(note);
                    }
                }
            }
            FilterResults filterResults = new FilterResults();
            filterResults.values = filteredList;
            return filterResults;
        }

        @Override
        protected void publishResults(CharSequence constraint, FilterResults results) {
            submitList((List) results.values);
        }
    };
```

In MainActivity:

```
mEditTextToolbarSearch.addTextChangedListener(new TextWatcher() {
    @Override
    public void beforeTextChanged(CharSequence s, int start, int count, int after) { }

    @Override
    public void onTextChanged(CharSequence s, int start, int before, int count) { }

    @Override
    public void afterTextChanged(Editable s) {
        noteAdapter.getFilter().filter(s.toString());
    }
});

mNoteViewModel.getAllNotes().observe(this, new Observer<List<Note>>() {
    @Override
    public void onChanged(List<Note> notes) {
        noteAdapter.submitList(notes);
        noteAdapter.setInitList(noteAdapter.getCurrentList());
    }
});
```

Comment: there is a problem related to `getCurrentList()`, please share this method with us

Comment: That is method you have when you extend ListAdapter in Adapter class, for example:
`public class NoteAdapter extends ListAdapter<Note, NoteAdapter.NoteHolder> implements Filterable {`

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You are getting [`UnsupportedOperationException`](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2887590/unsupportedoperationexception-on-collection/14066105) Due to using `.clear()` on `UnmodifiableCollection`

Looking into your code to see where you use `clear()`:

```
getCurrentList().clear();
```

So, definitly `getCurrentList()` is `UnmodifiableCollection`, so you can't modify it like normal Lists.

[The documentation](https://developer.android.com/reference/androidx/recyclerview/widget/ListAdapter#getCurrentList()) of `getCurrentList()` says:

> The returned list may not be mutated - mutations to content must be done through submitList(List).

So, you can mutate the `ListAdapter` `getCurrentList()` through [`submitList`](https://developer.android.com/reference/androidx/recyclerview/widget/ListAdapter#submitList(java.util.List%3CT%3E))

So, try to replace `getCurrentList().clear()` with `submitList(new ArrayList())`

Comment: You are right, I didn't notice that in documentation, I updated my question with code working correctly now. Thank you.

Comment: @Antonio Can you post the original code that was causing the error with the "clear" code that caused the problem?  And then show your corrected code.  That way we can see the problem and the solution.